# Android AccountManager Seemingly Not Invalidating Tokens

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication, google-authentication, android-account

I have an Android app that authenticates to AppEngine using `AccountManager`. It has been working for over a year now. While running some tests today, I noticed that the Set-Cookie header was missing from the response to `https://my-app.appspot.com/_ah/login?continue=http://localhost/&auth=...`. Therefore, I don't have a SACSID, and thus can't authenticate.

After looking into the issue further, I realized that this only happens when I use the account that is the admin of the AppEngine app (this account had no problem authenticating 2 weeks ago). I can sign in without issue in a browser, and non-admin users can get the SACSID using the auth token from `AccountManager`. I have tried invalidating the auth token and getting a new one, but that didn't work either. I also tried all the different permutations for https and http, and still nothing.

Anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

**EDIT:** Adding that no cookies are returned with the response at all.

**EDIT 2:** It seems that `AccountManager.invalidateAuthToken("ah", authToken)` is not working. After failing to get the SACSID cookie, I try to invalidate the token assuming that it is expired. However, I just checked, and the same token gets returned the next time I request one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the issue was that `AccountManager.invalidateAuthToken` needs to be called with `"com.google"` as the accountType not `"ah"`.